# XML Xpath for Windows event?

Tags: windows-7, window, xml, event-viewer, xpath

I'm trying to create an event filter based on the following event XML (an example), but I seemed to be missing something:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Events><Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
    <System>
        <Provider Name='acvpnui'/>
        <EventID Qualifiers='25600'>3021</EventID>
        <Level>4</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime='2016-04-08T22:01:57.000000000Z'/>
        <EventRecordID>35164</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client</Channel>
        <Computer>MyComputerName.domain.com</Computer>
        <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>Message type information sent to the user:
Connected to my.vpn.server.com.</Data>
    </EventData>
</Event></Events>
```

And I'm using the following XML XPath filter, but I get nothing back with it:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client">
    <Select Path="Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client">
Event
    [System
        [Provider
            [@Name='acvpnui'] and (EventID=3021)
        ]
    ]
    [EventData
        [Data and (Data='Message type information sent to the user: Connected to my.vpn.server.com.')]
    ]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

I could take out `and (Data='Message type information sent to the user: Connected to my.vpn.server.com.')]`, but then I get more than I want from the filter.  How do I filter for that particular EventData?

Comment: Is there a line break between the text `to the user:` and `Connected to my`? Also, could you share a valid export file as `.evtx` format from your event viewer?

Comment: Oh, yeah, there is, so I just changed the string to `'Message type information sent to the user:&#xA;Connected to my.vpn.server.com.'`.